# connect signalR with flutter

Tags: c#, flutter, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

`Hello: I am developing an app with signalR from .net and flutter but I have found little documentation about it. I don't know which library I should connect to. Can someone help me? I have been coming and there are endless libraries like: signalr_client, signalr_core, signalr_netcore and I don't know which one is correct, I managed to connect with signalr_core: 1.1.1 but it says that this library came out two years ago and the most recent one i found was signalr_netcore: 1.3.5 but i couldn't find a way to connect

I leave an example of my code with signalr_core  1.1.1`

I try to upload the code of the connection example but the platform won't let me

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** signalr_client, signalr_core, signalr_netcore and I don't know which one is correct ?

**Answer:** All of them are correct, they are flutter client for ASP.NET Core SignalR. The difference should be secondary encapsulated by different authors. It is still recommended to look at the GitHub Chinese files, if any.

I have check [the sample project](https://github.com/jamiewest/signalr_core) you mentioned, if you want use this sample, you need to know this is signalr client, we still need a signalr server. [Please follow the official doc to create the signalr server which using the javascript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

After that, run the web project and make the demo we create works well, then back to you Flutter project and change the port to the webapp is using.